# Passing the correct date format from PHP to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

The following PHP code echoes either today's or yesterday's date as selected by the user from a drop down. It echoes perfectly but it is failing to hit the DB correctly. All my other selected data gets sent just fine.

I have tried to absorb and interpret all the answers i have found online but i cant seem to crack it. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

if ($_POST["Date"]=='Today') {    
    $d=strtotime("today");

echo date('Y/m/d', $d) . "<br>";

} else {
$d=strtotime("yesterday");

echo date('Y/m/d', $d) . "<br>"; 
}
?>

$sql = "INSERT INTO `Basis Trades` ( `Date`,........etc

'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Date'])}',
```

Comment: so when does the db stuff follow? or do you feel that it was irrelevant? and if that POST array even has a value

Comment: '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['Date'])}',     sorry first time user...

Comment: I was a little intimidated about posting my first problem on a website like this precisely because of people like you Fred. I knew my question was low level but I really wasn't expecting to get hijacked and voted down within the first minute! I am pretty sure you are not typical of the users on this site and I look forward to interacting with some people who are genuinely helpful.

Comment: what the heck are you talking about??

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your dates are stored in the DATE data type and not VARCHAR, you are providing the date in the wrong format.

You are trying to insert a date in which is *just a word* (today, yesterday). You forgot to convert it, you just echo it out. Even so, it won't work anyway as your proposed format is YYYY/MM/DD. MySQL is expecting YYYY-MM-DD.

Your code "fixed"

```
if ($_POST["Date"]=='Today') {    
    $d=strtotime("today");
} else {
    $d=strtotime("yesterday");
}
$date = date('Y-m-d', $d); 
?>

$mysqli->real_escape_string($date)
```

Comment: I had used both the / and the - to format the date but it made no difference.  The date is echoing in the correct format as 2016-05-17.  $d=strtotime("today"); is a command that produces a date not just the word. I still cant get it working. And i am using 'Date' in my DB.

Comment: Read my answer again. You totally missed all of the mistakes you are making that I pointed out.

Comment: My apologies for missing the obvious but yesterday was a very long day. I have made the changes but still have not succeeded. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: You probably have an error elsewhere in your code. I can only guess at what it is.